# Android: com.facebook.Session cannot be resolved

Tags: android, facebook, session, parse-platform

I am importing the tutorial app from Parse at https://github.com/ParsePlatform/f8DeveloperConferenceApp, which involves linkage including login with Facebook.

### Question:

1. There is one place that has error that could not be resolved, as shown in the capture below. I have already added the required. Could anyone please tell me how to solve such? The error reads as `The type com.facebook.Session cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`
2. And would there be any samples related to adding users to ParseUser database after user login? I have tried login my own FB account sucessfully but my data is not added to the ParseUser db yet...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like your `facebook.jar` is older.

Comment: The facebook sdk is recently download at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Comment: then you should add `facbook lib` to your project

Comment: Yes I have added the fb library to the project already too .... but really dont know why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has removed the support for Sessions in new SDKS. Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232606/android-facebook-integration-impossible-to-import-com-facebook-session).