# Android - Facebook Integration: Impossible to Import com.facebook.Session

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, integration, facebook-android-sdk

i'm new on android - facebook integration.
I'm trying to integrate my app with facebook, so i follow all the steps on the [facebook tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android), and things work fine (at least i'm abble to perform the login). 
 
But when i try to use this following code, i realize that i can't import the library from the Facebook:

> Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

I'm using Android Studio, and the IDE only give me the option to import the **android.service.textservice.SpellCheckerService**, but i guess that the right import is **com.facebook.Session**
Any ideas of what i'm missing here?
**PS:** FB SDK version is facebook-android-sdk-4.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook remove session in new SDK. [check my answer for same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824694/unable-to-import-session-request-response-graphuser-packages-in-android/31825387#31825387)

there full integration code is given by me.

you can check whether user is logged in or not by this code.

```html
profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getCurrentProfile();
if (profile != null) {
 // user has logged in

} else {
 // user has not logged in
   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking around, i realize that the **Session** class on the new facebook SDK is not used.
Instead that i found something like this, it solved my question:

```
loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    Log.e("Content", "User ID: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "\n" + "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
    //"If login attempt canceled.";
}

@Override
public void onError(FacebookException e) {
    //"If login attempt Failed.";
}});
```